# MySQL query works for SELECT but not with UPDATE statement

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update, mariadb, mysql-error-1064

I am running into an issue where My first query ( SELECT ) works fine but When I try to execute my second query ( UPDATE ) I get an error. Can someone please help me to know what am I doing wrong here?

```
QUERY 1:

WITH res AS (
    SELECT str.request_id as requestID, str.type as incorrectType, TxType.utType as correctType
    FROM x str
    JOIN (
        SELECT tr.request_id, ut.type AS utType
        FROM x tr
        JOIN y tc ON tr.request_id = tc.request_id
        JOIN z ut ON tc.transaction_id = ut.id
    ) AS TxType ON str.request_id = TxType.request_id
    WHERE str.type != TxType.utType
    AND str.application = 'sample' LIMIT 1
)

SELECT * FROM x tr_req
JOIN res AS re ON re.requestID = tr_req.request_id
WHERE tr_req.type != re.correctType;

RESULT : SUCCESS
```

```
QUERY : 2

WITH res AS (
    SELECT str.request_id as requestID, str.type as incorrectType, TxType.utType as correctType
    FROM x str
    JOIN (
        SELECT tr.request_id, ut.type AS utType
        FROM x tr
        JOIN y tc ON tr.request_id = tc.request_id
        JOIN z ut ON tc.transaction_id = ut.id
    ) AS TxType ON str.request_id = TxType.request_id
    WHERE str.type != TxType.utType
    AND str.application = 'sample' LIMIT 1
)

UPDATE x tr_req
JOIN res AS re ON re.requestID = tr_req.request_id
SET tr_req.type = re.correctType
WHERE tr_req.type != re.correctType;

RESULT : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE x tr_req
```

Comment: Thanks @P.Salmon, I need a limit. There are over 900K records to update. I need to execute this in batches of few thousands to make sure it does not get timeout.

Comment: More on Chunking:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks (The principles apply to UPDATE.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using MariaDB. [Here is the documentation of WITH](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/with/).

As you can see in the syntax, it works only with SELECT:

```
WITH [RECURSIVE] table_reference [(columns_list)] AS  (
  SELECT ...
)
[CYCLE cycle_column_list RESTRICT]
SELECT ...
```

There is no UPDATE option.